# P-Channel MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, p-channel

I have the circuit below on a PCB. I am trying to provide 48V across R5 at power-on, then after a delay, disconnect R5 from the input power.

[image]

I have three questions regarding this circuit.

Question 1: At power-on, the load turns on as expected. However, it turns off for a brief moment and then turns back on. I probe the drain of Q2 and see this:
[image]

The voltage was rising and suddenly dropped almost to 0V then continued to rise. I suspect that this drop in voltage causes the issue I described above where the load loses power for a quick moment. What can I do to remove this voltage drop?

Question 2: How do I calculate the delay time? Is C1 charged through R2 and the delay time is five times the time constant? If so, it is 50 seconds; however, as a measure with an oscilloscope, R5 only sees 48V for about 170ms.

Question 3: How do I increase the turn-on time of Q2 so that the power is delivered to the load faster at power-on?

Comment: You've got rather a hefty MOSFET there. What's the actual load going to be (maximum current/minimum resistance)? Any capacitive component to the load?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it will be connected to a base of a NPN transistor, which has a 200kOhm base resistor and a resistor from base to ground with a value of 50kOhm. Though, for the above measurements, I disconnected the load and have an actual 100k resistor at the output instead (exactly like to schematic).

Comment: You have a BJT switching a MOSFET switching a BJT?  What is your end goal here?

Comment: @vir The load is an existing device so there is nothing I can change. I am making a control circuit which can output 48V.

Comment: Do you expect a fast turn off after the delay? Some spec is needed also what's the minimum input voltage & duration considered to be ON, what's the input voltage down situation (volts, how long) which resets this circuit for new power up. Slow turn off and reduced input voltage situations can be fatal if they are not specified properly. I guess your actual load is something else than 100k.

Comment: @arnold8a shouldn't the turn off be very quick because I am using a MOSFET? When the power is removed, the capacitor can discharge in several seconds to reset the circuit, it doesn't have to be extremely fast.

Comment: MOSFETs do not have a very sharp transition region, at least not in the sense that you need.

Comment: Have you already thought what behaviour you expect when the input voltage swings the full 48V or a part of it fast - maybe a poor connection or a fault. A fault shouldn't cause new faults. That's why some design is needed.

Comment: @vir Right now I don't see any issues with the turn off. The problem is that the load turn on-off-on at power on

Comment: Did you take into account that the Miller capacity plays a huge role in the switching behaviour of power mosfets? As soon as the fet starts conducting, that capacity needs to be charged while the \$U_{dg}\$ is reducing. From the look of it all that current has to go through a transistor with a base resistor of \$1 M\Omega\$. It depends on the \$ \beta \$ how fast that will go. My intuition (for as far as it's worth anything) is that this might be the cause of the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @HarryH I didn't. Also, don't you mean the base resistor of 10k? The transistor is off when the power is first applied.

Comment: I mean the 'dip phenomenon', that's during the transition. But I think @Kuba has explained it in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What can I do to remove this voltage drop?

   There is feedback from the drain of the MOSFET to the gate, because the gate is very weakly driven. The FQB7P20 MOSFET you're using has only about 30 pF of reverse transfer capacitance, but that's when it is fully OFF. As it turns on, the gate-drain capacitance increases significantly, and it is this parametric capacitance change that effectively "back-drives" the gate.

   You'll want a push-pull driver for the gate.
2. Is [...] the delay time is five times the time constant?

   No. The number of time constants depends on how far the capacitor charges as the percentage of supply voltage. In your case, the capacitor only needed to charge to 0.7 V/48 V=1.4% of the supply voltage to turn on Q1. Recall that when there's 0.7V across the capacitor, Q1 is already on.

   In the circuit below, the time constant is 75 s, and it takes slightly less than 1 time constant for Q1 to get turned on, since the capacitor only needs to charge to about 45-50% of the supply voltage.
3. How do I increase (sic) the turn-on time of Q2 so that the power is delivered to the load faster at power-on?

   I think you meant how to *decrease* the turn-on time of Q2, i.e. the time during which Q2 goes from "off" to "on" initially.

   Use a push-pull gate driver to drive the gate hard.

   As a very coarse approximation, assume that there's about 10nF between the gate and either source or drain.

This circuit should be a good starting point:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXpCFu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Transistors are rated for 300 V VCEO. D1 is rated for 200 V Vr.

D2 sets the capacitor threshold voltage to about 50% of supply voltage. D1 discharges the capacitor when the supply is removed. D3 protects the base of Q1 from reverse voltages due to spikes on the 48 V rail etc. Q2 and Q3 are a push-pull gate driver. Their base-emitter junctions are inherently protected from reverse voltage in this configuration. R4 is a stand-in for the load.

R1 sets the timing.

---

But anyway, if the load is actually as high as 100 kΩ, the big MOSFET is an overkill. You could use a transistor instead, and the circuit would be much simpler since there would be just one transistor if you want a somewhat smooth turn-off, or two transistors for a "snap" turn-off.

> it will be connected to a base of a NPN transistor, which has a 200kOhm base resistor and a resistor from base to ground with a value of 50kOhm.

A-ha! Yeah, the circuit you propose, with its rather enormous MOSFET, is total overkill. Two transistors is all you need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fidVUi.png)</sup>

---

Alternatively, a 74HC1G14 Schmitt trigger, and a smaller capacitor, will do the trick:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQhlNx.png)</sup>

R3 recharges C2 through 1G14's input protection diodes.

Comment: The "good starting point" circuit places 48 V across the FETs gate-source barrier.

Comment: The push-pull does solve the problem described in question 1. Now I can get the system to turn on the way I wanted. However, I am having trouble getting the timing circuit to work. After the delay, Q1 cannot stay completely on; it switches rapidly between on and off.

Comment: @AnalogKid The push-pull stage's input is kept within 24V of the top rail, so I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: @HV16 Which circuit are you having the trouble in? I suggest that the circuit with the single gate will be most robust. The transistor circuit I've shown is a starting point, it may need further tweaks. And in any case, that big mosfet you're using is silly and unnecessary. Use the two-transistor circuit instead.

Comment: I am having trouble only with the timing circuit (C1, R1, R2, D2, D3, and Q1). I removed Q2 from the circuit to test the timing circuit. R3 was initially left open as expected, then after a delay, Q1 started toggling. I don't have the exact components in your schematic, so I use 470kOhm for R1 and R2, 10uF for C1, and 20V for the zener D2.

Answer (score 1):

R4 in your design is a very weak way to assert potential at the gate, and what's happening is a sharp rise in drain potential, as the MOSFET switches on, is coupled back to the gate via parasitic gate-drain (miller) capacitance \$C_{GD}\$, which causes the MOSFET to switch back off.

This can be a tricky problem to solve, and has plagued engineers since the dawn of the MOSFET. This is why you have been advised to use a gate driver IC. Its low output impedance would be able to hold gate potential low in spite of the drain's fast rise. But I'll presume that's not what you want to do.

You have two obvious approaches to mitigating this miller effect. Either you slow the rise of drain potential, or you provide a gate signal of such low source impedance that it can hold gate potential low in spite of miller current at power on.

Another issue that complicates things is the transistor's intolerance for gate-source voltages \$V_{GS}\$ exceeding ±20V. The use of a zener diode to clamp \$V_{GS}\$ necessarily requires the gate driver to have significant impedance, to prevent ridiculously high currents through the diode, which as I explained above, is not a good thing.

That's two issues to solve.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjS6Xf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here I've employed an emitter follower, Q2, with very low source impedance when sinking current, and it should be able to oppose any rise in gate potential due to miller current at power on.

I've moved \$V_{GS}\$ limitation away from the gate itself. D3 now constrains Q2's base potential to be above 35V, which imposes a similar limit to the lowest potential possible at Q2's emitter and Q3's gate.

Everything from Q1 to the left is to do with timing. Initially C1 is discharged, potential \$V_X\$ at X will be +48V (when power is applied), and will slowly fall as C1 charges, via R2. When \$V_X\$ has fallen to +35V or so, D2 conducts, switching on Q1, and raising Q2's base potential. Q2's emitter follows, and Q3 switches off.

R1 and D1 ensure that the capacitor quickly discharges when supply potential \$V_{IN}\$ falls to zero, but they aren't strictly necessary. They won't help much if there's nothing else to force \$V_{IN}\$ to zero.

I haven't tested this, but I think it's worth a shot.

Physical layout is important in this application, whichever solution you choose. The main concern is that long meandering wires from Q3's gate to Q2's emitter, or between Q2's collector and ground will have inductance and resistance that you must keep to an absolute minimum. Keep those paths short and very low resistance. Even just a couple of ohms of resistance, or a few nanohenries inductance, will allow miller current to have a significant effect. Whether you are building this on a breadboard, or designing the PCB, use heavier gauge wires/traces, and keep Q2 and Q3 as close as possible, with leads/traces as short as possible between them.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit in the schematic does not make much sense to me.

A single P-channel MOSFET like Q2 together with an RC circuit at its gate should do the job. So remove everything except Q2, R3 and R4 and place C1 in parallel to R4.

Always start simple and only add complexity when needed.

Yes, the time constant times 5 is a good starting point, but it depends on R3, R4, C1 and the threshold voltage of Q2.

You might also need the zener diode D1 to protect the gate-source from too large voltage at startup.

Comment: Wouldn't C1 create a large Vgs and destroy the MOSFET if it were in parallel with R4?

Comment: Exactly  This is why you need the zener D1, but that should be it.

Comment: Then the capacitor now can only charge to 28V, assume that D1 is a 20V Zener. The MOSFET will never turn off.

Comment: Of course you need to tune the circuit, i.e. adapt the resistance values and the zener voltage to the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First pass at a less complex solution.  When power is applied, C1 charges up rapidly to 36 V, and Q1 snaps on.  Then R1 takes over and continues charging C1 up to 48 V.  At around 44 V, or 4 V Vgs, Q1 begins to turn off.  This turn-off point is dependent on the FET being used.  R2 provides a discharge path for C1.

One possible drawback to this circuit is that while the 48 V output snaps on rapidly, it turns off relatively slowly.  How slowly depends on the timing components.  Please update the question with the desired power-on time.

Note:  The vast majority of power MOSFETs cannot handle Vgs greater than 20 V, let along 48 V.  D1 clamps the max. Vgs at 12 V, a little above the specified voltage for minimum Rds, but well below a common max rating of 20 V.

[image]

UPDATE:

Based on a comment, here is an LTSpice simulation.  48 V power comes on at 1 s and goes off at 4 s.  The output pulse is free of any perturbations.  I increased R1 to show a wider output pulse.

[image]

Comment: While this circuit has a lower component count, its behavior upon power-on remains the same as described in the question

Comment: The simulation is clean.  See the Update.

Comment: I have the circuit built on a breadboard. The waveform is the same as the one attached in the question.

Comment: Does the simulation of your circuit match the scope shot in your question?

Comment: No. The simulation gives me the same result as yours.

Comment: Does the 48V supply sit rock-steady throughout the turn-on cycle?

Comment: Yes I belived so

Comment: Apart from the huge initial current through D1 and C1, which really should be mitigated somehow, this design is good. I can't see how the MOSFET could switch itself off due to \$C_{GD}\$, since C1 will not permit gate potential to rise. The only explanation I can think of, is that there's significant resistance or inductance between MOSFET gate and C1. Make sure that this wiring of the path is low impedance and very short. In fact for this application, all wiring must be short and stout. A breadboard with long meandering wires is very likely to be the cause here.

Comment: Also, C1 must be low ESR, preferably ceramic.

Comment: C1 ceramic - At a 100 V rating I prefer film or stacked metal foil.  AND the higher the ESR/ESL the better, because:  Inrush - that's why R1 is so large - it makes C1 smaller.  Also, LTS shows an inrush spike of 5 A for 10 microseconds, which is trivial for a 1 W zener.  Finally, "the only explanation I can think of" is that it is something outside of the circuit.  The two circuits are different in their operation, and both are fine in simulation.  To show the same problem IRL indicates that the problem is outside the circuits.

Comment: As something to try quickly, put 100 ohms in series with C1. This will limit the peak inrush current to 360 mA, and slow the Q1 turn-on ramp by about 20x. This should eliminate any inductive wiring effects.  More importantly, it will reduce the transient current demand seen by the power supply.